# Understanding `RegionNearest`

Tags: regions

As far as I understand `RegionNearest`-function the last command

```
p = {x1, y1};
np = RegionNearest[Disk[]][p]
abs=(np - p) . (np - p) (* scalar *)
```

gives a   result

[image]

which is scalar!

But if I substitude point p by `{x1->1/2,y1->1/3}`

```
abs /.{x1->1/2,y1->1/3}
(*{1/36, 1/36}*)
```

I get a list of values?

What's wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Your `abs` is not a scalar, it has a list inside of it (and squaring a list gives a list of squares) ... I think the problem is in `np - p` not "combining" the components in `List` and `Piecewise` correctly.

Comment: @Domen Thanks for your comment. `p`and `np` both are lists! Scalar product should give a scalar I think.

Comment: Observe what happens in this simpler case: `{x1, y1} + Piecewise[{{{x2, y2}, cond}}, {x3, y2}]`. `Piecewise` gets distributed into each component! So if you then do `% /. cond->True`, you don't get one vector – as one might expect.

Comment: Relevant questions: [Prevent Plus from threading](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102721/prevent-plus-from-threading), [Sum of two Piecewise functions give wrong vector](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69612/sum-of-two-piecewise-functions-give-wrong-vector). One of the possible solutions: `abs = (np~plus~-p) . (np~plus~-p); abs /. {x1 -> 1/2, y1 -> 1/3} /. plus -> Plus`